# Is it possible to keep track of selected rows in Activeadmin on multiple pages?

Tags: activeadmin

My activeadmin has a list of rows among many pages with a "selectable" column.

Users should be able to select multiple rows using the selectable columns across multiple pages (while paginating). When a user clicks between pages, however, their previous selections are lost. It seems activeadmin only keeps track of row selection on one page.

Is it possible to keep track track of row selections across multiple pages?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a cool feature but it is not available in ActiveAdmin or any extensions I know of. I suggest adding some AJAX to update a shadow list when the selectable column is clicked then override the batch actions to reference the shadow list when submitted.